# Что такое трёхмерные массивы?

Tags: массивы

Как устроенны трёхмерные массивы: что у них — строка, что — столбец, что — третье?

Как с ними работать? Как представить геометрически?

Comment: что именно вам непонятно? И что вы подразумеваете под "геометрическим представлением"?

Comment: видимо, куб. а стиль вопроса захватывает..

Comment: ...и тут Остапа понесло...

Comment: Нда с таким подходом 4-х мерные массивы вообще будут разрывом шаблона?

Comment: почему разрывом. Обычный себе [тессеракт](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82).

Comment: Мне лично больше нравится, как в релятивистской теории Эйнштейна,  рассматривание 4-й проекции как времени.

Answer (score 6):

Представьте Кубик Рубика. 3-мерный массив `3 x 3 x 3`

Comment: там, как минимум кубика не хватает)

Answer (score 5):

Трёхмерный массив можно представить как стопку двумерных таблиц.

Например, в случае с **Книгой** третье измерение будет Страницами.

Тогда получится, что на каждой Странице есть таблица [Строки, Колонки].

Answer (score 2):

Третье можно назвать глубина(в геометрическом смысле) или слой

Answer (score 0):

Можно представить как массив 1-мерного, точнее с 3d+ массивом на 1-2d (память) нормально работать не получится я думаю. Там так и устроено, что-то вроде чтения всей строки сразу. Можно сравнить так - рукой можно двигать в любом направлении за одинаковое время, памяти компьютера придется перескакивать неизвестное кол-во раз (зависит от упаковки массивов), для 3-мерного (x, y и время/кадры) видео например реально близкие (соприкасающиеся) точки будут удалены на x*y точек. Это все значит если представить как в памяти программы - то это массив массивов массивов:), метр - сантиметр - мм), как-то так.
Может для удобства, незнаю, в opencv 3-d вроде как обычная стопка а не массив-массивов, работал только с 2-d так-что могу ошибаться. Как там доступ будет из 1-го к последнему хотелось бы знать